# How do I define a secondary value if a Firebase value is nil

Tags: ios, firebase

In my app, I have a function that used to return an email, but of course my beta testers would like me to use a user name rather than making their email public. Problem is, not all users have defined a user name.  I can switch the child path, but the app crashes for everyone whenever they encounter a user who didn't enter a user name on signup.  While I will want to change this later, this seems like a good exercise: How do I get a secondary value if the requested value is nil?

```
func getUsername(forUID uid: String, handler: @escaping (_ username: String) -> ()) {
        REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userSnapshot) in
            guard let userSnapshot = userSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
            for user in userSnapshot {
                if user.key == uid {
                    handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String)
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you explain a little further? I'm doing something similar in my app so i may be able to help you. What I'm unsure about is where is at crashing at? Does it crash if they don't enter a username or does it crash after firebase looks for a username but one doesn't exist? You need to put more code. and show exactly where the crash is happening or the nil value is being pulled or set

Comment: The crash occurs when Firebase looks for the user name and the error is logged as Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10c7ee850) to 'NSString' (0x10b9672a8).  The idea here is that there is a "users" node which sometimes has the name and there is also a "profile" node which also contains the name.  I am wondering if there is way to have firebase search a second location if the first is nil or doesn't exist. And then of course, if neither exists it should either use a default value or move on without a crash.  I am new to swift so don't be afraid to point out the obvious.

Comment: use a default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is what's causing the crash:

```
handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String)
```

The reason is by using the bang operator `!` your force unwrapping it and casting it as a String here: `as! String`. The problem is if there is nothing there and a `nil` value is returned you can't cast `nil` as a `String`.

eg. this is what it's seeing when there is a nil value returned:

```
handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String)
// since user.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value == nil it sees
handler(nil as! String)
```

The main thing to understand is that by force unwrapping something using the `!` your saying that whatever it is it's definitely not `nil`. Thus *when it is nil* then there will be a **crash**. If you are unsure about what will come back then you should use a `?` and safely unwrap using optional binding `if let`, a `guard` statement, or a nil coalescing operator `??` like explained below

You have to use an `Optional` inside your handler so it can accept nil.

Try this.

Make it so that your handler can accept an Optional of type String:

```
handler: @escaping (_ username: String?) // the question mark after the String makes it optional
```

Then when the handler is called use the nil coalescing operator `??` to provide a default value if the username is nil:

```
handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String ?? "defaultValue")
```

Here's your code:

```
func getUsername(forUID uid: String, handler: @escaping (_ username: String?) -> ()) {
        REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userSnapshot) in
            guard let userSnapshot = userSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
            for user in userSnapshot {
                if user.key == uid {
                    handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String ?? "defaultValue")
                }
            }
```

Here's an the answer to your question in the comments below. In your handler I changed the return type from () to String? so it can accept an Optional of type String. I changed it from:

```
func getUsername(forUID uid: String, handler: @escaping (_ username: String?) -> () {
```

to:

```
func getUsername(forUID uid: String, handler: @escaping (_ username: String?) -> String? {
```

Try this:

```
func getUsername(forUID uid: String, handler: @escaping (_ username: String?) -> String?) {
        REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userSnapshot) in
            guard let userSnapshot = userSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
            for user in userSnapshot {
                if user.key == uid {

                    // 1. you no longer use the nil coalescing operator because if you use it then you can't get a nil value
                    // 2. declare a local variable and name it value of Optional type String meaning it will accept nil or a String
                    var value: String? = handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String)
                    print("+++++value is: \(value ?? "value is nil")")                            

                    // 3. run a check on the value. If value is == nil then try your other node but you should probably use the nil coalescing operator there
                    // if value != nil which means username above returned a value other then nil then this won't run
                    if value == nil {
                       print("the username node was nil so use this different node")
                       value = handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "theDifferentNode").value as? String ?? "someDefaultValue") // if for some reason this is nil then this will have some default value
                       print("-----value is now: \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Lance!  That solves the crash and your explanation really makes it clear what I need to understand moving forward.  Now that it will survive the the nil value, could I construct an if/else statement to use a different node if the value is nil?

Comment: let me know if the additional answer I added to the bottom works

Comment: OK.  This is very good and I am getting where things happen in firebase.  I get an error, thoug for the value variable line: Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'String?'.

Comment: This is my fault, I just noticed its a function that doesn't return anything that's why there's an error. When you created your handler, you created a closure that takes an Optional of type String argument but doesn't return anything: (_ username: String?) -> (). When i created value i made it an Optional of type String but the problem is your handler doesn't return anything so the 2 don't match up, do you understand that? I have to change the code, I'm going to delete what I wrote for that part and I'll try to think of something. Keep it commented out on your part. It'll help you learn

Comment: What I originally wrote works. I tried it on my end and it worked for me so it should work for you. Try it and let me know if you have any problems

Comment: DataService.instance.getUsername(forUID: message.senderId) { (email) in
            cell.configureCell(profile_image: UIImage(named: "defaultProfileImage")!, email: value!, content: message.content, senderId: message.senderId)
        }

Comment: What’s that’s mean? Looks like a shared instance from your Firebase file that gets the users info. I didn’t see that in your initial question

Comment: OK, Now when I call the function, I get an error...Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'String?'  What I am trying to do is input the result to an field that was previously called email.  Ignore the code above which is where I was trying to make it work.

Comment: This is the original call in the table cell...DataService.instance.getUsername(forUID: message.senderId) { (email) in
            cell.configureCell(profile_image: UIImage(named: "defaultProfileImage")!, email: email!, content: message.content, senderId: message.senderId)
        }

Comment: Seems like a different question with a different setup because you didn’t have anything about a tableview cell above. You should create an entirely new question for 3 reasons. 1 you get answers from different people. 2 you add code specifically relevant to the question. 3 your questions and the answers from them help other people learn. If you keep it part of this same question it gets lost in translation. Make a new question, post all the tableview code, send me a message and I’ll look at it and try to help you out.

Comment: I understand.  Thanks for your patient help with this.  I definitely learned way more than how to solve this simple problem.